# SQL Server Database Diagram in SQL Management Studio creating multiple schemas

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, schema

I'm using a multiple schema approach (**Multi-Tenant arhitecture**) in the same DB and it's working great. I can use EF bounded contexts and split domains appropriately.

> According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx), multi-tenant architecture can be a shared server
>   (separate dbs), shared database (separate schema), or shared schema
>   architecture.

Currently i'm writing TSQL to get the DB design i want but I would like to know if there is a way to choose the schema before creating a new table when using Database Diagram tool in SQL Management Studio?

Comment: A better multi-tenant approach IMHO is to have a separate database per client, rather than a separate schema. Management is about the same, but moving a client to its own server is easier, and you don't need a *unique* set of objects per client - in each database they can all be identical, they just contain different data.

Comment: I understand. Using multiple schema is a better approach in my case. I can easily define security per schema and bounded context with EF. Thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Database Diagrams is one of three [**Visual database tools**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212949.aspx).

After reading trough [**Visual Database Tools F1 Help**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186789.aspx), where there is no mention of choosing schema before creating a new table, which confirms that it automatically creates the table in the **dbo** schema.

To overcome this and still use Database Diagrams open your [**Table Properties**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189415.aspx) window.

1. Create new schema:

[image]

2. Name your schema, define permissions etc.

[image]

3. Change schema for your table while in design view using **Properties** window.

[image]

For me this approach is still faster that writing scripts, i didn't change to different designer tool and it works.

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, in the diagrams created by Management Studio the tables will be created in the dbo schema. Even if the connected user has a different default schema, it will still create the tables in the dbo schema.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. So there is no override or some other approach?

Comment: The best approach I see is to actually write your own scripts and not rely on the diagramming tool to generate them for you. If you really want to use an ERD tool, I think that you can check those of [this list](http://www.databaseanswers.org/modelling_tools.htm). But I really prefer to write every script myself.. :-). I could recommend you give a try to Power Designer, which is a great tool in itself, but I'm sure there are others.

Comment: I don't want to use other designer tools. For now i will investigate further and leave this question open. Thanks for replaying.